# Finding all records with more than 3 values in one column between other two values in that column

Tags: sql, oracle

for example I have table:

```
COL_0   COL_1   COL_2
11111   BBBB    RECORD DELETED
11111   BBBB    RECORD ADDED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   BBBB    RECORD ADDED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   CCCCCC  RECORD ADDED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   BBBB    RECORD ADDED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   BBBB    RECORD ADDED
11111   CCCCCC  RECORD ADDED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   BBBB    RECORD DELETED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   BBBB    RECORD ADDED
11111   BBBB    RECORD ADDED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   CCCCCC  RECORD ADDED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   BBBB    RECORD DELETED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   BBBB    RECORD ADDED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   BBBB    RECORD ADDED
11111   CCCCCC  RECORD ADDED
11111   AA      lalala
11111   BBBB    RECORD DELETED
```

COL_0 is id and in real table there are many different id's.
COL_1 is link to another table.
COL_2 is operation on that other tables.

That can't be changed. Problem is that app doesn't work properly and delete record in some situations. Now I need to find all id's where between two "RECORD DELETED" are more than 3 "RECORD ADDED". Is there some way for that?

Br,

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column specifying the order of the rows.

Comment: To further elaborate, don't you have any time-relaeted information -timestamp for each operation? Without it, you can't really do anything

Comment: There are created and changed time. I must find all for six months back but i don't know more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using analytic functions -- assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering.  I will assume there is a `dte` column with this information.

I would start by identifying groups, using a cumulative sum of record deleted records.  Then I would count the added records in each group:

```
select id, min(dte), max(dte)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when col_2 = 'RECORD DELETED' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col_1 order by dte) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where col_2 = 'RECORD ADDED'
group by id, grp
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Note:  This gives every occurrence where this happens.  If you really just want the ids, then you can use `select distinct` with `group by` -- one of the rare occasions when this is an apt solution:

```
select distinct id
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when col_2 = 'RECORD DELETED' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col_1 order by dte) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where col_2 = 'RECORD ADDED'
group by id, grp
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Comment: Yes, there is column that specifies order. Thanks I will try something with this and report back.

Comment: I'm missing something... I use 
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when col_2 = 'RECORD DELETED' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col_1 order by dte) as grp
      from table_name t
     ) t and that returns every id from table.

Comment: @MikeL . . . That is the subquery.  The outer query only returns rows with `RECORD ADDED`.  Did you run the full query.

Comment: Yes, I paste only this because only new thing is table_name "...from table_name t) t where col_2 = 'RECORD ADDED'...".